# Pythonic way of checking if several elements are in a list

Tags: list, python

I have this piece of code in Python:

```
if 'a' in my_list and 'b' in my_list and 'c' in my_list:
    # do something
    print my_list
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Something like (invalid python code follows):

```
if ('a', 'b', 'c') individual_in my_list:
    # do something
    print my_list
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if set("abc").issubset(my_list):
    # whatever
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. As I told Jochen, it's going to be tough to pick between your answer and his. So I will pick whichever got more up votes in the next 20 minutes. Thanks again!

Comment: Also: `if set("abc") <= set(my_list): pass`

Comment: `if set('a','b','c').issubset(my_list)` is the more general form.

Comment: @Ethan: Yes, as long as you put in another pair of parens. :)

Answer (score 10):

The simplest form:

```
if all(x in mylist for x in 'abc'):
    pass
```

Often when you have a lot of items in those lists it is better to use a data structure that can look up items without having to compare each of them, like a `set`.

Comment: More specifically, if you have a lot of items in the `('a', 'b', 'c')` iterable, a set is the better choice.  The number of items in `my_list` does not matter.

Comment: What is elem supposed to be in this example? Generates `NameError: "global name 'elem' is not defined"`. I assume it's meant to be `x`

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: thanks a lot for the answer and clarification. It's going to be tough to pick between your answer and Sven's. So I will pick whichever got more up votes in the next 20 minutes. Thanks again!

Comment: In `if all(x in mylist for x in candidates):` it's the length of the candidates that doesnt matter, as you have to loop over each element in it no matter what. The `x in mylist` test becomes slower the longer `mylist` gets (in the worst case where all candidates are at the end of the list), to the point where converting `mylist` to a `set` first will be faster.

Comment: @JochenRitzel: You are right.  My comment was about comparing your answer to my answer.  If `candidates` is short, they are both about the same speed, regardless of the length of `mylist`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use set operators:

```
if set('abc') <= set(my_list):
    print('matches')

superset = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
subset = ('a', 'b')
desired = set(('a', 'b', 'c'))

assert desired <= set(superset) # True
assert desired.issubset(superset) # True
assert desired <= set(subset) # False
```